# Column Validation for day Monday OR Friday

Tags: 2010, date-time, validation, calculated-column-formula

I'm working with a date and time column and need a validation that returns true if the day of the week is Monday OR Friday. Users are not permitted to add an item on any other day of the week.

```
=TEXT([Date & Time],"dddd")="Monday"
```

This formula works perfectly for allowing only dates that are a Monday, I just need to add Friday into the same validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, why all those nested IFs??

The [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/WEEKDAY-function-a9784177-5c31-4deb-bc9e-d4ab914983ca) returns a number 1-7 for weekdays, starting at 1=Sunday

So to validate Monday, Thursday and Friday use:

```
CHOOSE( WEEKDAY([Start Date]) ,false ,true ,false ,false ,true ,true ,false )
```

An optional second parameter makes the [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/WEEKDAY-function-a9784177-5c31-4deb-bc9e-d4ab914983ca) start at other days of the week

Comment: Danny thank you so much, I can adapt this easily for future requests too. Cheers

Comment: Have since documented all [Functions and Syntax](http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List) you can use in Calculated Columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(TEXT([Date & Time],"dddd")="Monday",TRUE,IF(TEXT([Date & Time],"dddd")="Friday",TRUE,TEXT([Date & Time],"dddd")="Thursday"))
```

Comment: @Steven if this solution worked, please mark as the answer and/or rate up the answer.

Comment: I have, it wouldn't let me mark it as the answer straight away. Said I had to wait 5 mins..

Comment: Amal I've just had the request changed to include Monday, Thursday, and Friday. Are you able to help me with altering the formula to include Thursday as well?

Comment: Try the updated answer.